# solution to avoid setting an ajax request as synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, prototypejs, synchronous

Good day!

I would like to ask if there is a work around besides setting an ajax request to synchronous? I am using prototype.js and apparently I encountered a problem wherein removing my alert statements(debugging purposes) produces an unexpected output. I then put again the alert statements and surprisingly, the output is normal again. I have searched the internet and found out that what is happening actually is that there are incomplete tasks between the server and client that needs to be finished before the next ajax request fires/runs. I tried to make that particular ajax request synchronous and luckily I got my expected result. But, I noticed that the web page becomes slower to load and I've read some articles that setting an ajax request to synchronous is not good. Is there a work around with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does involve a bit of a restructure to your code, but if using plain JS you need to define a callback function for `onreadystatechange` of the Ajax request and do the next step in your processing from there - any good Ajax tutorial should explain how. But since you are using Prototype you might as well use the library functions that make it much easier: http://prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request (take a look at the `onSuccess` callback).

Comment: Hi, I am actually using the onSuccess and onFailure callbacks. Do you think I should use any other? Here is what happens, I need to populate a drop down list based from another selection to another drop down list. After this, i need to select an option as default to the supposed to be populated drop down list. I think the setting of default option to be shown is futile since it fires before the list is populated. Do i make sense? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the default within the `onSuccess` callback after you populate the list. (Sorry, I don't know much about Prototype, being more of a jQuery man, but I assume the concept is pretty much the same).

Comment: Can you [show some source code](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)? It helps if the problem can be reduced to a minimal [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @nnnnnn hello! sorry for the delayed feedback! I was a bit busy. I followed your advice and it was correct! :) Thank you very much. I realized that my problem is a bit shallow haha I think I need to enhance my logic skills. Thanks again and please do help me again if I happen to encounter a problemn again :)

Answer (score 0):

is your question "how to set ajax request to asynchronous?"
*(because a synch request stops other thing from working until this request completes)*
answer is >>
if you using $ajax you can set asynch to false as below

> $.ajax({
>    url: "some.php",
>    **async: true**
>   })

or simple code based on XMLHTTPRequest

> var url="url to call";
>  var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
>   request.open("GET",url,**true**);

Comment: Hi, good day! thanks for this information, but what i need are work around suggestions so that i would not set my ajax request as "synchrounous".

Comment: `$.ajax` is jQuery, this question is specifically about Prototype.